# Add two columns, i,e. mean_a and mean_b

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
# Price
0  1.00
1  12.23
2  3.24
3  12.67
6  149.98
7  19.98
8  1883.23
9  1.99
10 4.89
11 9.99
12 12.99
13 18.23
14 17.99
15 18.98
16 18.11
17 19.10
18 20.30
19 1901.30
20 20.27k
```

Suppose I have the previous dataframe. I would like to add two columns, `mean_a` and `mean_b`. `mean_a` would compute the mean of the next `k` levels and `mean_b` will compute the mean of the previous `k` levels. For instance, at `#10` with `k=3`, `mean_a = (4.89 + 9.99 + 12.99)/3 = 9.29` and `mean_b = (4.89 + 1.99 + 1883.23)/3 = 630.0366667`. How can I implement that in python?

I have tried that, but I don't think it is good

```
def moving_average(self, df, col_name='smooth_midprice', k=10):
        ma_cols = []
        mb_cols = []
        temp_df = pd.DataFrame()

        for i in range(0, k+1):
            ma_col = 'M_A_{}'.format(i)
            ma_cols.append(ma_col)
            mb_col = 'M_B_{}'.format(i)
            mb_cols.append(mb_col)
            temp_df[ma_col] = df[col_name].shift(i)
            temp_df[mb_col] = df[col_name].shift(-i)


        df['M_A'] = temp_df[ma_cols].mean(axis=1, skipna=True, numeric_only=True)
        df['M_B'] = temp_df[mb_cols].mean(axis=1, skipna=True, numeric_only=True)
        return df
```

Comment: You use pandas rolling: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[You can just using `rolling`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) (Notice `.iloc` is to reverse the order of the df)

```
df['mean_a'] = df.Price.rolling(3,min_periods =1).mean()
df['mean_b'] = df.Price.iloc[::-1].rolling(3,min_periods =1).mean()
df
Out[9]: 
      Price      mean_a      mean_b
0      1.00    1.000000    5.490000
1     12.23    6.615000    9.380000
2      3.24    5.490000   55.296667
3     12.67    9.380000   60.876667
6    149.98   55.296667  684.396667
7     19.98   60.876667  635.066667
8   1883.23  684.396667  630.036667
9      1.99  635.066667    5.623333
10     4.89  630.036667    9.290000
11     9.99    5.623333   13.736667
12    12.99    9.290000   16.403333
13    18.23   13.736667   18.400000
14    17.99   16.403333   18.360000
15    18.98   18.400000   18.730000
16    18.11   18.360000   19.170000
17    19.10   18.730000  646.900000
18    20.30   19.170000  647.290000
19  1901.30  646.900000  960.785000
20    20.27  647.290000   20.270000
```

Fix your code

```
col_name='Price'

k=10
ma_cols = []
mb_cols = []
temp_df = pd.DataFrame()

for i in range(0, k + 1):
    ma_col = 'M_A_{}'.format(i)
    ma_cols.append(ma_col)
    mb_col = 'M_B_{}'.format(i)
    mb_cols.append(mb_col)
    temp_df[ma_col] = df[col_name].shift(i)
    temp_df[mb_col] = df[col_name].shift(-i)

df['M_A'] = temp_df[ma_cols].stack().groupby(level=0).head(3).mean(level=0)#change 3 to k 
df['M_B'] = temp_df[mb_cols].stack().groupby(level=0).head(3).mean(level=0)

df
Out[35]: 
      Price      mean_a      mean_b         M_A         M_B
0      1.00    1.000000    5.490000    1.000000    5.490000
1     12.23    6.615000    9.380000    6.615000    9.380000
2      3.24    5.490000   55.296667    5.490000   55.296667
3     12.67    9.380000   60.876667    9.380000   60.876667
6    149.98   55.296667  684.396667   55.296667  684.396667
7     19.98   60.876667  635.066667   60.876667  635.066667
8   1883.23  684.396667  630.036667  684.396667  630.036667
9      1.99  635.066667    5.623333  635.066667    5.623333
10     4.89  630.036667    9.290000  630.036667    9.290000
11     9.99    5.623333   13.736667    5.623333   13.736667
12    12.99    9.290000   16.403333    9.290000   16.403333
13    18.23   13.736667   18.400000   13.736667   18.400000
14    17.99   16.403333   18.360000   16.403333   18.360000
15    18.98   18.400000   18.730000   18.400000   18.730000
16    18.11   18.360000   19.170000   18.360000   19.170000
17    19.10   18.730000  646.900000   18.730000  646.900000
18    20.30   19.170000  647.290000   19.170000  647.290000
19  1901.30  646.900000  960.785000  646.900000  960.785000
20    20.27  647.290000   20.270000  647.290000   20.270000
```

Comment: Can you tell me if the attempt in the code is well done or not? What about the NaN in your example? Can you decrease or increase the `k` depending if you are at the beginning or the end of the listing?

Comment: @Jeremie use the `min_periods` param

Comment: @Jeremie using the min_periods=1 and change the windows to whatever you need

Comment: If you can modify your answer to have a real mean at the place of the NaN values, I will accept your answer.

Comment: Can you tell me what is wrong with the attempt in my question?

Comment: Btw, the result you gave is not good. At #18 for exemple, `mean_a` should be `(20.30+1901.30+20.27)/3=647.29`

Comment: @Jeremie There are many questions about your solution tbh. I'd separate the function to do one thing.

Comment: @Jeremie Maybe he confused a and b.

Comment: Just change your answer, and I will accept it definitely

Comment: @Jeremie you can check mean_b, I think I just over look mean_a, mean_b

Comment: @Jeremie also fix your code, and base on your output and mine out put they are same :-)

Answer (score 2):

Like @Wen said: you can caculate `mean_a` using a rolling function:

```
df['mean_a'] = df['Price'].rolling(3).mean()
```

`df['mean_b']` is just `df['mean_a']` shifted by -2

```
df['mean_b'] = df['mean_a'].shift(-2)
```

This returns:

```
    #   Price   mean_a      mean_b
0   0   1.00    NaN         5.490000
1   1   12.23   NaN         9.380000
2   2   3.24    5.490000    55.296667
3   3   12.67   9.380000    60.876667
4   6   149.98  55.296667   684.396667
5   7   19.98   60.876667   635.066667
6   8   1883.23 684.396667  630.036667
7   9   1.99    635.066667  5.623333
8   10  4.89    630.036667  9.290000
9   11  9.99    5.623333    13.736667
10  12  12.99   9.290000    16.403333
11  13  18.23   13.736667   18.400000
12  14  17.99   16.403333   18.360000
13  15  18.98   18.400000   18.730000
14  16  18.11   18.360000   19.170000
15  17  19.10   18.730000   646.900000
16  18  20.30   19.170000   7397.200000
17  19  1901.30 646.900000   NaN
18  20  20270.00 7397.200000 NaN
```

**EDIT:**

If you want to avoid some values being NA, you need to use the `min_periods` parameter. We can create `mean_a` by `df['mean_a'] = df['Price'].rolling(3, min_periods = 1).mean()` ,but now we can't create `mean_b` by shifting - I couldn't think of another straightforward way other than @Wen's method for that. (reversing the `price` series of the subsection where `df['mean_b']` is `na`:

```
 df['mean_b'] = df['mean_a'].shift(-2)
 df['mean_b'][df['mean_b'].isna()] = df['Price']df['mean_b'].isna()].iloc[::-1].rolling(3,min_periods =1).mean()
```

; but then it could be less involved if we just reversed the whole series in the first place.

Comment: Can you tell me if the attempt in the code is well done or not? What about the NaN in your example? Can you decrease or increase the k depending if you are at the beginning or the end of the listing?

Comment: If you can modify your answer to have a real mean at the place of the NaN values, I will accept your answer.

Comment: How can you due with the bot NaN value ?

Comment: @Wen *Thinking*

Comment: @Wen I went the full cycle and came back to your method :(

Comment: Yep , that is hard to due with the NaN :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
def moving_average(df, k=10):
    mean_a = pd.Series()
    mean_b = pd.Series()
    for i in range(df.shape[0]):
        mean_a = mean_a.append(df.iloc[i:i+k].mean(), ignore_index=True)
        start_b = i-k+1 if i-k+1>=0 else 0
        mean_b = mean_b.append(df.iloc[start_b:i+1].mean(), ignore_index=True)

    hold = df.copy()
    hold["mean_a"] = mean_a
    hold["mean_b"] = mean_b
    return hold
```